# get_user_pages() to pin memory across syscall

Tags: linux-kernel

According to the the kernel inline comment to the gup api:

> "This does not guarantee that the page exists in the user mappings
>   when get_user_pages returns, and there may even be a completely
>   different page there in some cases (eg. if mmapped pagecache has been
>   invalidated and subsequently re faulted). However it does guarantee
>   that the page won't be freed completely. And mostly callers simply
>   care that the page  contains data that was valid *at some point in
>   time*. Typically, an IO  or similar operation cannot guarantee
>   anything stronger anyway because locks can't be held over the syscall
>   boundary."

I assume I have to `put_page()` before return to the user space. But I also find that the `ib_umem.c` `get_user_pages()` in a syscall and `put_page()` back in another syscall. I want to do the same in my driver. Is that same?

Thanks.

update on Nov 10, 2016:
OK, now I know the reason. gup can pin the page so it would not be freed. But it cannot lock the vma to point to the same page. The ib_umem do not solve the problem, the ib_umem_get() and ib_umem_release() should remain in the same syscall scope.

I also found some solution such as  http://lwn.net/Articles/600502/. It tried to introduce a VM_PINPED flags to pin the VMA. But it seams nobody be interested in. Why?

Comment: Why don't yout just mlock? What do you need this for in the first place?

Comment: mlock can just ensure the memory "in the memory", but it cannot ensure the page remain in the same place.